# How to replicate ora-12155 Exception?

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc

How can I replicate Ora-12155 Exception?

I want to replicate Ora-12155 Exception in a Test environment using Spring JDBCtemplate.

Comment: What database version and what JDBC driver version? To get the JDBC driver version use > java -jar <jdbc-jar>.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "replicate". In general you can raise any exception like this:

```
DECLARE
    INTERNAL_TNS_ERROR EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(INTERNAL_TNS_ERROR, -12155);
BEGIN
    NULL;
    RAISE INTERNAL_TNS_ERROR;
END;
```

Comment: I see this exception in production. After this exception, the application would not hang and require a server restart. I just want to know how I can fix this.